# Quick smoke effect doesn't provide fire speed option (3.5)

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation, fire

I'm trying to make my smoke expand faster. I was watching this tutorial: https://youtu.be/ew1cr665u7M?t=60

Don't see any of the fire stuff in Blender 3.5